# VBA Code to Copy worksheets containing named ranges from source to destination workbook

Tags: excel, worksheet, named-ranges, vba

I have 2 workbooks. A Source workbook and a destination workbook. They are completely same except for 1 worksheet which has the same name in both but different data (both contain around 30 sheets). What i wanted was to Copy the rest of the identical worksheets from source workbook to destination workbook leaving that 1 worksheet which defers in data.

Basically the identical worksheets present in the destination workbook should be replaced with the ones from the source workbook. The worksheets contain formulas and named ranges.
I was successfully able to write the VBA Code to copy the worksheets. But since the named ranges have a workbook scope. The named ranges still refer to locations in the source workbooks. So i get 2 named ranges with the same name. Something like:

```
'The one already present in the destination workbook (from the worksheet which was replaced)
Name=VaccStart , Refers To =Sheet2!$A$2 
'The one due to the copied worksheet.
Name=VaccStart , Refers To =[C:\Users\.....\Source.xls]Sheet2!$A$2
```

I want the named ranges to refer to the destination workbook and not the source workbook when i copy them. Since all the sheets in both the workbooks are same and i am just replacing them.

Comment: What's your code for when you copy the worksheet?

Comment: `SourceWorkBk.Worksheets(i).Copy Before:=DestWorkBk.Worksheets(myindex)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to get around inadvertent link creation when moving from a source to destination workbook is to relink the destination workbook from Source to itself

Screenshot for xl2010

- Edit .... Links
- 'Change Source" and pick the current file as the new source

[image]

Comment: My whole process is to be automated since it will do the same thing in a loop for around 200 workbooks. So instead of a manual thing. Can you tell me a vba code for this?
Also, i just discovered that along with the named ranges, the Formulas are also still linking back to the sourceworkbook. How can i fix that?

Comment: This works like a charm. here is the code i used
`DestWorkBk.ChangeLink Name:=SourcePath & "\" & SourceFileName _
        , NewName:=DestPath & "\" & DestFileName, Type:=xlExcelLinks`

Now is there a code to remove duplicate named ranges?

Comment: Yes - you could run this code and then further code using a Dictionary object to find indentical concatenated names and sheet addresses. I suggest its a new question :)

Answer (score 1):

This will modify the named ranges to remove the external file reference:

```
Sub ResetNamedRanges()
    Dim nm As Name
    Dim sRefersTo As String
    Dim iLeft As Integer
    Dim iRight As Integer

    For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        sRefersTo = nm.RefersTo
        iLeft = InStr(sRefersTo, "[")
        iRight = InStr(sRefersTo, "]")
        If iLeft > 1 And iRight > 0 Then
            sRefersTo = Left$(sRefersTo, iLeft - 1) & Mid$(sRefersTo, iRight + 1)
            nm.RefersTo = sRefersTo
        End If
    Next nm
End Sub
```

Comment: hey this works well rachel. But after copying around 30 sheets, i end up getting multiple duplicate named ranges of the same name. Wot i thought of is to delete all the named ranges from destination after copying the sheets and then copy paste all the source names to destination. Tell me if this makes sense.

Comment: `For Each nm In DestWorkBk.Names
nm.Delete
Next
For Each nm In SourceWorkBk.Names
DestWorkBk.Names.Add Name:=nm.Name, RefersTo:=nm.RefersTo
Next`

Comment: I'm a little unclear as to whether you have two sets of named ranges in the destination wbk (source wbk & original destination wbk) or whether there's just one set and the references are pointing to the wrong file. I suggest you try @brettdj's suggestion to see if that works. It might work to first delete the named ranges from your destination file... try that, too.